# Unit Test Friendly way of using membership details inside the controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, asp.net-membership

Here is a piece of code from one of the **controller** inside my **ASP.NET MVC 3** App :

```
_destinationdetailRepository.Add(new DestinationDetail { 

    DestinationID = destination.DestinationID,
    CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
    CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name
});
```

What is important here is the **CreatedBy** property value which is `User.Identity.Name`. It works great and I use this on another parts of my app as well. But, I guess this is not a *unit test firendly* way of doing things.

So, what is the way of using Membership data inside the controller so that I will be happy when I am unit testing my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, I guess this is not a unit test firendly way of doing things.

No, it's unit test friendly and it is correct code. The [`User`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.user.aspx) property is an [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) interface that can be mocked in an unit test.

Comment: So cool. I will dig into that. Found bunch of stuff already. Thanks !